# How to return true/false in a block in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm doing something like this:

```
myarray.delete_if{ |x|
   #some code
   case x
   when "something"
       return true
   when "something else"
       return false
   end
```

The "return" statement seems wrong, and I can't figure out the right syntax, I understand the simplistic form of: `myarray.delete_if{ |x| x == y }`, but not when my desire to return true/false is more procedural as in the case statement example.

Comment: `myarray - ["something"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove `return`. In Ruby, the last value evaluated is used as return value.

```
myarray = ["something", "something else", "something"]
myarray.delete_if { |x|
  #some code
  case x
  when "something"
    true
  when "something else"
    false
  end
}
myarray # => ["something else"]
```

You can use `next` if you want to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to particularly condition the `false` cases. They can be `nil` by default if you do not condition them.

```
myarray.delete_if do |x|
  ...
  case x
  when "something" then true
  end
end
```

or even better:

```
myarray.delete_if do |x|
  ...
  "something" === x
end
```

I do not know what you have in the `...` part, but if you just want to remove a certain element from an array, you can do:

```
myarray.delete("something")
```

and if you want to get back the receiver, then:

```
myarray.tap{|a| a.delete("something")}
```

Comment: To be completely exact, `case` statement works by calling `#===` method on the case objects. Therefore the brief way of precisely reproducing the OP's code behavior in your style would be: `a.delete_if &"something".method( :=== )`

Comment: @BorisStitnicky It looks like the OP has some pre-processing to do before the conditional/case statement.